# How to reverse ArrayList input?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I am working on my application **Reflects Input**

**Example**

When user enters 1, 2, 3. ArrayList will reverses and prints 3,2,1
How i can do this with ArrayList?

> INPUT 1, 2, 3
>
> OUTPUT 3, 2, 1

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: Can you describe your question with more detail?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try:

```
ArrayList<Object> objects= new ArrayList<Object>(objects);
Collections.reverse(objects);
```

Or you can add them at front:

```
objects.add(0, yourObject);
```

Comment: With great pleasure ! :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep the original array. You can copy the reverse of the array into a new array like so.

```
ArrayList original = new ArrayList();
ArrayList copy = new ArrayList();
    for(int i=original.size()-1; i>=0; i--){
        copy.add(original.get(i));

    }
```